# How can I get my real VPS Internet speed?

Tags: bandwidth, vps

I'm using IntoVPS's product (VPS)
I tried to download a Windows 7 ISO, a torrent game, Photoshop from archive.org link
and they all download around 2-5 MB/s 
I've tried servers from Fermont, London, and others... all the exact speed.

If I try to download from Ubuntu (an Ubuntu image), it goes for the real speed (50-100 MB/s)

What is the problem? How do I get the real speed?

Comment: Could you be more specific? You tested the speed by downloading files to or from the VPS? There are many factors that can limit download speeds. Try downloading several files from different servers at the same time.

Comment: I am downloading from Internet onto the VPS